# If h, k be continuous maps between $S^1$ with the same degree, then they are homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology

> If $h, k : S^1 \to S^1$ have the same degree, they are homotopic.

I want to solve this exercise and I made a proof of this, but I feel like there’s something wrong. So I hope somebody would check it.

Let deg h = deg k = n
Let $b_0 = (1,0) \in S^1$

Let $q : I \to S^1$ be a map defined by $q(s)=(cos2πs,sin2πs)$.

Define $h’ = h \circ q$. Similary $k’ = k \circ q$.
Then $h’$ is a loop at $h(b_0)$ and $k’$ is a loop at k(b_0).

Note that $q$ is a loop at $b_0$ and generates $π_1(S^1,b_0)$

Thus, $h_\ast (q) = h’ = nq(h(b_0))$, where $q(h(b_0))$ is a generator of $π_1(S^1, h(b_0))$.

Similarly, $k_\ast(q) = k’ = nq(k(b_0))$

Let $p : R \to S^1$ be a covering map. 
Choose $h_0 \in p^{-1}(h(b_0))$ and $k_0 \in p^{-1}(k(b_0))$.

Then there exists a lifting $f$ of $h’$ starting at $h_0$. 
Also there exists a lifting $g$ of $k’$ starting at $k_0$.

Then, since $q(h(b_0))$ is a generator, $f(1) = h_0 + n$.
Similarly, $g(1) = k_0 + n$.

But $R$ is contractible. So $f$ and $g$ is homotopic.
Thus $h’$ and $k’$ are homotopic ( just composite p to f and g). —————— ($\star$)

So there exists a homotopy $F : I \times I \to S^1$ between $h’$ and $k’$.

$q \times id : I \times I \to S^1 \times I$ is a quotient map.

Thus it defines a continuous map $G : S^1 \times I \to S^1$ via $F$. And this is the homotopy between $h$ and $k$.

This is the end of the proof.

I’m not sure this is right because I feel missing something. I didn’t use the assumption that they have the same degree. I’m doubt that ($\star$) is true.

Could anyone help me to find what’s wrong and improve this proof?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made a great start.

THe problem is that to show $h$ and $k$ are homotopic *as loops*, you need to show that they're homotopic *holding the endpoints fixed*. That amounts to showing that $f$ and $g$ are homotopic *holding endpoints fixed*.

NB: I was assuming that $h$ and $k$ have the same start point; if not, you need to first find a homotopy from, say, $k$ to $k_1$ so that $k_1$ has the same start-point at $h$. You can do this as in the comments, or you can do it by gradually rotating to get the endpints aligned...both work.

The great thing about $\Bbb R$, for this problem, is not so much that it's contractible, but that it's a vector space. You can define

$$
H(x, t) = (1-t)f(x) + t g(x)
$$

That's a homotopy from $f$ to $g$ (fix $t = 0$, and you've got $x \mapsto f(x)$; fix $t = 1$, and you've got $x \mapsto g(x)$.

But the key thing is that
$$
H(0, t) = H(0,0
$$
and
$$
H(1, t) = H(1, 0)
$$
for all $t$, i.e., the endpoints never move up in the universal cover. So in the projection to $S^1$, the loop-endpoints stay right where they're supposed to stay.

Edit to clarify the "match the basepoints" thing.

Suppose $h$ is a loop at $\alpha \in S^1$, and $k$ is a loop at $\beta \in S^1$; you should think of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as angles in this case, and points of $S^1$ as corresponding to angles via "mod 2 pi".

Define
$$
U(x, t) = h(x) + t (\beta - \alpha)
$$
Then $U$ is clearly continuous in $x$ and $t$, and $U(x, 0) = h(x)$, but $x \mapsto U(x, 1)$ is a loop $h'$ that is homotopic to $h$, but with $h'(0) = \beta$ instead of $\alpha$.

Now all you need to show is that $h'$ and $k$ are homotopic, *knowing that they start and end at the same exact point*; my construction of a homotopy $H$ above does the job for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I have a question. f and g in my proof can have the different end points so that I can’t guarantee to make a homotopy fixing end points.

Comment: I found ‘Thus it defines a continuous map $G : S^1 \times I \to S^1$ via $F$‘ is wrong because F is not path-homotopy. So I need F to be path-homotopy but f and g have the different end-points..... ummm

Comment: Ah, right.. I missed that. Suppose $h$ is a loop at $x_0 \in S^1$, and $k$ is a loop at $x_1$. Let $\gamma$ be a path from $x_0$ to $x_1$. Then $\gamma$ followed by $k$ followed by $\gamma$-in-the-other-direction is a loop at $x_0$ as well, and still has the same degree as $k$ (indeed, it's homotopic, as a loop, to $k$). Call that $k_1$. Now you have $h$ and $k_1$ have the same degree AND the same basepoint, so path lifting can give you $f$ and $g$ with the same start-point...and then degree-equality gives the same end-point, and then my homotopy solves the problem.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I think I understand most of it! But I don’t know why $k$ and $k_1$ are homotopic. Umm $k$ is homotopic to $\gamma\ast k$ ?

Comment: See my addition at the end of the answer, constructing a homotopy from $h$ to $h'$, where $h'$ is a curve that starts/ends at the same point that the loop $k$ starts/ends at.